# Kolmogorov-Arnold representation theorem, but for symmetric functions

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I will use the following formulation of the Kolmogorov-Arnold theorem:

**(Theorem)** A continuous multivariate function $f$ can be expressed as
\begin{align}
f(x_1, \cdots, x_m) = \sum_{i=1}^{2m+1} \Phi \left( \sum_{j=1}^m \phi_{i,j}(x_j) \right)
\end{align}
where $\Phi, \phi_{i,j}$ are all continuous

Define a "symmetric function" as a function of $m$ variable whose value given $m$ arguments is the same regardless of the order of the arguments.

For symmetric functions, can we prove something like:
\begin{align}
f(x_1, \cdots, x_m) = \sum_{i=1}^{2m+1} \Phi \left( \sum_{j=1}^m \phi_i(x_j) \right)
\end{align}

Intuitively, it seems like it would hold because the symmetry of $f$ should eliminate the need for $\phi$ to peek at the position ($j$) of the input $x_j$.

Comment: This is known as the Deep Sets representation theorem, proved in the appendix here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.06114.pdf